# while creating a login page using django I get this error

Tags: python, django

First I have urls.py inside template folder in users (my app) folder.

`"""URLs for app=Users"""

```
from django.urls import path

from django.contrib.auth import login

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns =[
    # Login page
    path('login/', login, {'template_name':'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

Then I get login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name' this error. So I've been searching on internet for answer and changed it to:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns =[
    # Login page
    path('login/', LoginView, {'template_name':'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

however I am now getting this error: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

I have my login.html in a folder named users inside templates folder. Can someone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Django documentation for LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView):

> If you’d prefer not to call the template registration/login.html, you
>   can pass the template_name parameter via the extra arguments to the
>   as_view method in your URLconf. For example, this URLconf line would
>   use myapp/login.html instead:
>
> ```
> path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html')),
> ```

Change what you have to:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html')),
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. 'not call template' meaning when url matches it will just send it to django's login and also make its default template? Also if I change it page won't load...

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post the contents of your `users/login.html` file? You have to create your own template for the login. By default it's called `registration/login.html`, so you'd have to create that template. You said you have a `users/login.html`, so use that one instead. See the docs for sample contents for that file that you can use to test it out.

Comment: It says  auth_views is not defined so I tried import LoginView as auth_views and it gives me AttributeError: type object 'LoginView' has no attribute 'LoginView'

Comment: I put my html as an answer.

Comment: Since you're importing LoginView from `auth.views` just remove `auth.views` before LoginView. Also don't post edits to your question as answers, use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54740131/edit) below the question to make changes.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I'm struggling to make a test version of this work myself. Django can be tricky!